# Стереть весь вывод программы

Tags: python-3.x, linux, консоль

Когда закрывается приложение написанное при помощи библиотеки на подобии ncurses (vim, mc, htop) - его вывод (интерфейс) пропадает и курсор приглашения ввода переходит на следующую строку (будто вывода и не было). Как это можно реализовать на Python без ncurses или подобных библиотек типа termbox, npyscreen и подобных?

Comment: Для винды: `os.system('cls')`, для других ОС свои команды, но для линукса, по-моему `os.system('clear')`

Comment: @gil9red, оно не очищает экран, а переносит курсор в вверх экрана скрывая всё за верхней границей - прокрутить вверх и всё видно!

Comment: 1) Тут написано, что очищает экран https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLS_(command)  2) проверял эту команду в cmd и conemu, и не было возможности прокрутить, поэтому считаю, что это было очищение экрана

Comment: @gil9red Это зависит от эмулятора терминала... И да, у меня линукс! Меня не волнует как работает ```cls```.

Comment: clear так работает)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1.

> Как это можно реализовать на Python без ncurses или подобных библиотек?

Можно сделать также как `ncurses` - с помощью альтернативного буфера экрана [The Alternate Screen Buffer](https://www.xfree86.org/4.8.0/ctlseqs.html#The%20Alternate%20Screen%20Buffer).

Не все терминалы обладают данной функциональностью - например, виртуальный терминал (`tty`). Если запустите `top` или `less` в `tty` терминале, то увидете, что предыдущее содержимое экрана уходит вверх после запуска подобных программ. Узнать тип терминала можно с помощью команды `echo $TERM`.

Код для `xterm-256color` терминала:

```
from time import sleep

print("\033[?1049h", end='')         # Переключиться на альтернативные буфер экрана
print("\033[H", end='')              # Установить курсор в левый верхний угол

print("Alternate_screen_string_1")
print("Alternate_screen_string_2")
print("Alternate_screen_string_3")
print("Alternate_screen_string_4")
print("Alternate_screen_string_5")
print("Alternate_screen_string_6")

sleep(3)                             # Пауза нужна, чтобы успеть увидеть содержимое альтернативного буфера

print("\033[?1049l", end='')         # Переключиться на обычный буфер экрана
```

#### 2.

Как работает `ncurses` программа можно посмотреть следующим образом:

**2.1.** Создаём минимальную программу c `ncurses`:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{   
    napms(25000);               /* Пауза нужна, чтобы было время поймать процесс с помощью strace */
    initscr();
    printw("Hello World !!!");
    refresh();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

**2.2.** Компилируем и запускаем:

```
gcc curses_hello_world.c -o curses_hello_world -lncurses

./curses_hello_world
```

**2.3.** Переходим в другой терминал и подключаемся к процессу `curses_hello_world`:

```
sudo strace -s 99 -p $(pgrep curses_hello_wo) 2>&1 | less
```

**2.4.** Ждём 25 секунд и получаем системные вызовы, которые делала наша программа во время работы. В данном случае нас интересует системные вызовы `write`:

```
write(1, "\33[?1049h\33[22;0;0t\33[1;39r\33(B\33[m\33[4l\33[?7h\33[H\33[2J", 46) = 46
write(1, "Hello World !!!", 15)         = 15
write(1, "\33[39;1H\33[?1049l\33[23;0;0t\r\33[?1l\33>", 32) = 32
```

С расшифровкой этих эскейп последовательностей мне помогли [здесь](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/584416/109397) (на английском).

Comment: Ого! Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: Вы проделали не малую работу!

Answer (score 1):

Чуток нето, но можно затирать строку после каждого вывода.

```
import time
for i in range(30):
    print(i, end='')
    print('\r', end='')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Весь вывод в 1 строчку.нет захламления консоли и нечего очищать.

Comment: а вывод моей программы будет в несколько строк и никак иначе.

Comment: меня интересует, как это делают программы на ncurses (полагаю остаток вывода связан с тем, что пайтон интерпретируется, с curses-софтом на си такого не происходит)

Comment: Можно взять библиотеку tkinter и сдлать там вывод через label и рядом кнопку очистки нарисовать или авточистку сделать..но это же будет не консоль.для ввода нужно будет тоже поля делать

Comment: Сейчас бы графен по ssh :)

Comment: @Евгений а какие проблемы с графеном по ssh?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev а разве их нет? Будет либо не подключение к дисплею, либо софтина откроет окошки на стороне сервера (не проверял, поэтому конкретно сказать не могу)

Comment: Окошко можно рисовать отдельно)

Comment: @Евгений, у-у, есть многое на свете ©, например, man ssh в сторону "-C" и "-X"

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev x11 forwarding? Это, конечно, хорошо, но не это моя цель.

Answer (score 1):

ncurses делает это через создание нового терминала

```
root@route:~# ls /dev/pts/
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ptmx
root@route:~# mc

root@route:~# ls /dev/pts/
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  ptmx
```

7 - окошко, 8 - командная строка снизу

Как он это делает точно не знаю, но мне кажется через подмену дескриптора управляющего терминала.

Comment: А в этом есть смысл!